# Closing Mac Applications Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to make an app that can close any application you tell it to.

I have tried NSApp terminate:nil
but it closes my app instead of the one i want it to close

How do I close any application on my mac using objective c.

Comment: What other features will this app have and how will it be used? I think you'll be better off using AppleScript or Automator instead (for this particular task).

Answer (score 3):

Use the `runningApplications` property on `NSWorkspace`:

```
NSArray<NSRunningApplication *> *runningApplications = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace].runningApplications;

NSRunningApplication * app = runningApplications[n]; // find the app you want to kill
[app terminate];
// or:
[app forceTerminate];
```

Documentation: [`NSWorkspace`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/runningApplications), [`NSRunningApplication`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRunningApplication/terminate)

Answer (score 1):

Below code I used for kill my (Daemon) app.

```
- (BOOL) terminateService:(NSString *) bundleId{
    BOOL res =NO;
    for ( NSRunningApplication *app in [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications] ){
        if ( [bundleId isEqualToString:[app bundleIdentifier]] ){
            res = [app forceTerminate];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `NSRunningApplication` and the bundle identifier of the application

```
NSArray *applications = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.mail"];
if (applications.count) {
  [(NSRunningApplication *)applications[0] terminate];
}
```